# unable to set imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

In Xcode, storyboard, how to set a constraint so image view can be located 50% of total window height from the top of the superview?(including navigation bar) And we need it to be that way for ALL supported iOS devices (4s,5s,5,6)of all orientations.

Comment: use equal height and set multiiplier

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, hold ctrl and drag the imageView to it's superView (you can do it from the left menu), and choose Equal Heights.

A new constrain will show up. Go to this constrain, and, this time from the right menu, set the multiplier to 2 (or to 0.5)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set constraints by control dragging from your imageview to either the view or surrounding objects for top and bottom.

OR

create an outlet for the imageview in the correct View Controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!
```

then go to your viewdidload and use the code.

```
imageView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height / 2
```

if you want to change the location of the object you can use

```
imageView.frame.origin.x (or y) = (your placement)
```

once you create the outlet make sure to go to the storyboard in the connections panel on the upper right hand corner and drag from the circle to the left of imageView to your imageView in the viewController.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

let imageName = "percent.png"

let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height/1.8)
 view.addSubview(imageView)

or we can also set by percentage  like
screensize.height * 0.50(set as per requirement)

tahnks for help